# How to generate a url with Laravel's url generator helper with parameters that are not at the end?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Normally it is very simple to add parameters using the Laravel `url` helper method -- as simple as:

```
url("foo/show/", [333]); // site.com/foo/show/333
```

However, how do you do it when parameters are at a midpoint, such as:

```
url("foo/?/bar/?/show", [333,444]);
```

I have tried the following which all fail (some come close though):

```
url("foo/?/bar/?/show", [333,444]); 
// site.com/foo//333/444?/bar/?/show

url("foo/{a}/bar/{b}/show", [333,444]);
// site.com/foo/{a}/bar/{b}/show/333/444

url("foo/{a}/bar/{b}/show", ['a' => 333, 'b' => 444]);
// site.com/foo/{a}/bar/{b}/show/333/444
```

The `?` is obviously important, because it gets close to the result...

#### Note

I am specifically talking about unnamed routes. So the `route` function is not in question. Named routes aren't possible in the current project, so I need to reiterate I am looking for the use of the `url` method.

I 100% agree that normally named routes are the way to go.

Comment: Simple solution: name your routes. You look like you're deliberately trying to build the URL yourself. You can actually build it yourself (with concatenation), or you can name your routes (and allow Laravel to find the registered route and pull out parameters from it).

Comment: Named routes would help, but aren't an option in this case (and thus, yes a deliberate choice). And yes, my current solution is simple concatenation - am simply looking if there was a built in solution - which I think there is considering the `?` gets me close.

Comment: Anyone want to comment on the downvote? The question isn't off topic, nor covered in the documentation. The question also offers current state, attempted solutions and desire goal..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
url(sprintf("foo/%d/bar/%d/show", 333, 444));
```

Comment: Nice - I was hoping to leverage the underlying functionality of Laravel/symphony' url generator. Purely from a consistency point of view

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this approach rather than hardcoding url on different pages.

```
Route::get('foo/{param1}/bar/{param2}/show', array('as' => 'someRoute', 'uses' => 'SomeController@someMethod'))
    ->where(array(
        'param1' => '[a-zA-Z0-9-]+', 
        'param2' => '[a-zA-Z0-9-]+'
    ));
```

Controller:

```
public function someMethod($param1, $param2)
{       
    return $param1 . $param2;
}
```

// Assuming you passed params in controller

```
{{ route('someRoute') }}
```

// If not

```
{{ route('someRoute', ['param1' => 'test', 'param2' => 'routing']) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you name your routes, you can use the `route` function.

```
Route::get('some/{test}/{a}/testing', ['as' => 'testRoute', 'uses' => 'SomeController@someMethod']);

Route::get('test', function() {
    echo route('testRoute', ['test' => 'green', 'a' => 'purple']);
});
```

This would output `http://yourapp.local/some/green/purple/testing`

Answer (score 1):

If parameters are not `GET` request parameters, but parts of the path at a midpoint (like exactly asked in a question), it is possible to generate url using [Laravel's `url()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url) without using `sprintf()` at all:

```
url('foo', [333, 'bar', 444, 'show']);
// site.com/foo/333/bar/444/show
```

**However, as pointed in other answers – [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes) are preferable.**